# RxJS & Angular 8 - consecutive material dialogs based on previous dialog answer

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I have an fairly complicated scenario I'm trying to solve in the most elegant way possible:

- A case has multiple stages.
- Some stages require additional information
- I have a StateTransition service that checks the case and based on certain conditions presents a particular MatDialog
- If the user wants to jump over to a later state, system will present the applicable dialogs in succession (first present dialog A, then based on the result of this dialog (true / false) we present dialog B)

This is what I have so far:

```
test(case: Case){   
    let succession: Observable<boolean>[] = [];
    succession.push(this.openApplyDialog(case));
    succession.push(this.openWonDialog(case));

    concat(...succession)
    .pipe(switchMap((res, i) => {
      return of(res);
    }))
    .subscribe(() => { console.log('this is done now') })
}

[...]

private openWonDialog(case: Case): Observable<boolean> {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<WonDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(WonDialogComponent, {width: '600px'});
    dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogRef = dialogRef;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.id = case.id;
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }

private openApplyDialog(case: Case): Observable<boolean> {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ApplyDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(ApplyDialogComponent, {width: '600px'});
    dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogRef = dialogRef;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.id = case.id;
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
```

But this currently opens both dialogs one after another (without waiting for the "afterClosed" observable to complete.
Does anyone know how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that approach is that you have to open the dialog in order to listen to when it gets closed. Instead, you could try something along the lines of the following, which is more generic in that it listens to any dialog:

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.dialog.afterOpened.subscribe((ref: MatDialogRef<any>) => {
    console.log('dialog opened', ref.id);
    ref.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => { 
      console.log('dialog closed', ref.id);
      // something here to open the next dialog based on the result
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `from` and `flatMap` combo like:

```
test(case: Case){   
    let succession: Observable<boolean>[] = [];
    succession.push(this.openApplyDialog(case));
    succession.push(this.openWonDialog(case));

    from(succession).pipe(
      flatMap(observable => observable)
    )
    .subscribe(() => { console.log('this is done now') })
}
```

`from` will emit the values one by one, while `flatMap` will block the emission until the inner observable emits a value.

Examples:

1) `from` and `flatMap` visualization:

https://rxviz.com/v/xOvnEE7O

2) `concat` and `switchMap` visualization:

https://rxviz.com/v/j8Ad33NJ